# Can I create a screenshot of Google Chrome window with gpu enabled

Tags: c#, google-chrome, screenshot

Basically what I am trying to do is create a small program that creates a screenshot of a specific window. Right now I am using CaptureWindow from the Windows library.

```
public class ScreenCapture
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);


    public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        // get the DC of the target window
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);

        // get the size
        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        //int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        //int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        int width = 800;
        int height = 800;
        // create a device context we can copy to
        IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);

        // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
        // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
        IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);

        // select the bitmap object
        IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);

        // bitblt over
        GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy | CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt);

        // restore selection
        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);

        // clean up 
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

        // get a .NET image object for it
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

        // free up the Bitmap object
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

        return img;
    }

    private class GDI32
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
            int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
            int nXSrc, int nYSrc, CopyPixelOperation rop);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
            int nHeight);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
    /// </summary>

    private class User32
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
    }
}
```

This does work for most applications except Google Chrome will give a white or black image. When I run Google Chrome with --disable-gpu it does work but this is not really what I am looking for.